# I am not able to install easy_install in my ubuntu

Tags: apt, python

i have to install Review board in ubuntu, i tried following commands but i am getting error

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools.


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-setuptools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package python-setuptools has no installation candidate
```

Then i tried below command but for this also i am getting error message:

```
apt-get upgrade

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What should i do? Please help me out!!!!!

Answer (score 16):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

`sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

**Reasons behind the errors**
**Error1:**

```
Package python-setuptools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package python-setuptools has no installation candidate
```

This happens when you are trying to install a package about which APT does not have any idea. When you add software sources and then do an apt-get update your system APT's database is updated with all the packages on the repositories listed in software sources list.

Then when you try to install any package, apt checks the package name in it's database, finds it and checks the name of the repo from where it got it. It then downloads the package from that repo.
**Error2**:

```
  apt-get upgrade

    E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

This means that you are not the root user.So we use `sudo` to execute it as root

Comment: Even after typing the above commands i am getting same error message.                                                                   E: Package python-setuptools has no installation candidate.              After using sudo apt-get upgrade:               testpc1@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. easy_install has been removed from `python-setuptools`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1052682/519931

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use `easy_install`, but try `pip` instead.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Now you can use it in almost the same way as `easy_install`, but with better package management.

```
sudo pip install <pypi-package>
```

Comment: After running above command i am getting below error message:                                               testpc1@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package python-pip

Comment: Some reasons why you should use pip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second issue (could not open lock file) you find [here](http://xkcd.org/149/).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python3 virualenv for installing the desired package via easy_install, try installing python3-pip first by running

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and then install the required package via

```
pip install <desired-package>
```