# easy_install: command not found

Tags: 18.04, python-2.7, mycroft

I am trying to install MYCROFT on Ubuntu 18.04 following this: [LINK](https://mycroft.ai/documentation/linux/#prerequisites)

```
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core.git
cd mycroft-core
bash dev_setup.sh
```

I am getting this error:

```
sudo: easy_install: command not found
```

This error is because the script **dev_setup.sh line 168** is trying to execute:

```
easy_install pip==9.0.1 # force version of pip
```

I have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

However the

> easy_install

command is still not recognised. Any ideas?

***Update:***

By commenting out that line in the script allows the script to run. However there is a module error, **voice recognition module missing**, when doing an audio test.

Comment: I can't reproduce your errors on clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (both with `--depth=1` and without). Do you have python-related PPAs?

Comment: `easy_install` is part of `python-setuptools`. Please add the output of `apt policy python-setuptools` to your question.

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to `pip install python-setuptools` and run easy_install by full-path'ing it:

```
python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py pip
```

I prefer this over installing the `python-pip` system package because `pip` is moving faster than the distros update it, so I install it from PyPI.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was frustrating myself because I was using `find / -xdev -name easy_install` so I wasn't finding easy_install.py (because of the `.py` extension). You probably just saved me from trying some ridiculously desperate solution.

Comment: You're welcome!  A trick I keep in my back pocket when `find` doesn't return anything is falling back to a more fuzzy search like: `find / -iname '*easy_install*'`.  This will return files containing case-insensitive `easy_install` anywhere in the name; even if it's prefixed or suffixed with something.

Comment: An easier version than this is to run `python -m easy_install pip`

Answer (score 12):

According to the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-setuptools/39.0.1-2) `easy_install` was removed from the `python-setuptools` package.

I've got no good news for you; I've not found a solution short of updating the legacy scripts to use `pip` (and hoping the version `pip` installs works).

In your case its `pip` you're trying to get from `easy_install`, so you can probably omit the line since the version of `pip` in bionic is `9.0.1-2`.  A better change to the script might check that `pip --version` is less than `9.0.1` before trying to install that alternate version via `easy_install`.

Comment: lol to anyone struggling to load a 3rd party library that provides .egg files! And provides .whl files that are "incompatible with your system"!

Answer (score 10):

I got this from this link: [I am not able to install easy_install in my ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350312/i-am-not-able-to-install-easy-install-in-my-ubuntu).

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install <pypi-package>
```

Credits to: https://askubuntu.com/users/157039/m-tarun
and https://askubuntu.com/users/20837/timo

Comment: This is an absolute no-go. https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/868497

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I got the same error several times, I searched on many links but didn't get a useful solution.

For this, the version of the pip should be less than or the same as 9.0.1.

First of all, install the pip for python version 3 from-

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and check pip version-

```
pip --version
```

after that, we have to install build-essential for python-dev

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

and python setup-tools

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And finally, we are able to install pymongo by following command-

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

It worked for me, may it will work for you too.

Comment: This worked for me, but I used `sudo apt install python-pip` instead of installing python 3

Answer (score 1):

easy_install is not a part of python setup-tools so instead you can go for pip3 for installing python modules if pip is not found the following should solve your issue.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score -1):

> This worked on my side, all others mentioned here failed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pip
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
```

Comment: This answer nearly replicates the approach mentioned in the question. So no real improvement.

Comment: Cannot you see the difference? What do you mean by "nearly" replicates? Elaborate

Comment: In the [above answer given 5 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126574/51957) the same packages were suggested to install. Hence no improvement. Most of these packages were even mentioned in the question as well.

Comment: You still cannot see the difference, I have no energy wasting explain anything; Just Chill